# How can I tell the difference between Major Version and Minor Version?

Tags: version-history

I am using SharePoint 2013. I am using Version History for Documents. Furthermore, I have decided to use Major Versions and Minor Versions. My question is, how can I tell the difference between a Major Version and Minor Version of a Document?

I read that Major Versions have a whole number and a Minor Versions have a decimal number. I only see decimal numbers for both.

Thanks for your help.
[image]

Comment: You have 2 minor versions, no major version so far,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is only minor versions on your document library. You have enabled major and minor versioning on your document library, and unless users don't publish a major version, the documents will continue to save like minor versions.